# yum shows unresolvable URLs

Tags: yum, repository, oracle-linux

I have an instance in the Oracle Cloud based on Oracle-Linux-7.7-2020.02.21-0

yum update and any other yum command yields the following error:

```
...
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from ol7_UEKR5: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://yum-.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/UEKR5/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: yum-.oracle.com; Unknown error"
```

The following command shows lots of base URLs that can't be resolved:

```
yum-config-manager |grep yum\-

baseurl = http://yum-.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/UEKR5/x86_64/
baseurl = http://yum-.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/addons/x86_64/
...
```

Obviously an unresolvable URL:

```
ping yum-.oracle.com
ping: yum-.oracle.com: Name or service not known
```

This would work:

```
ping yum.oracle.com
PING e10877.dscd.akamaiedge.net (2.17.176.87) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

**What happened and what can I do?**

**Update:**

I have tried:

```
yum clean all
```

The file /etc/yum.repos.d/oracle-linux-ol7.repo shows the usage of a variable `$ociregion` in all base urls:

```
baseurl=http://yum$ociregion.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7...
```

The file /etc/yum/vars/ociregion contains only a `-`
So I made a backup of it an deleted this sign, leaving an empty file.

Now the yum-config-manager only shows valid URLs starting with yum.oracle.com, but `yum update` returns a new, different error:

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from ol7_ksplice: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/ksplice/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Comment: Obviously the URL is invalid. The problem is the `ksplice` component of the URL: https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/index.html exists, but https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/ksplice/x86_64/index.html doesn't. Check http://ksplice.oracle.com/ for the right way to install the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change I applied to solve the problem was to change the content of the file /etc/yum/vars/ociregion from `-` to `-eu-frankfurt-1` (my OCI region). Then `yum update` performed 575 updates without further problems.

Comment: How do you determine your OCI region?